# Pact Testing - Json Request body with multiple key value pair in object, but keys can be anything

Tags: pact

I have a json request body as below -

*`{"attributes":{"key1":"abc","key2":"xyz"}}`* - not just limiting to 2 key-value pairs. can be any number (1 or more)

key1, key2 - can be any string value. i.e - In one request key1 can be "Age", in Next request - key1 can be "Name".

How to generate PactDslJsonBody for this request.

My code -

```
PactDslJsonBody dsl = new PactDslJsonBody();
        dsl.object("attributes")
        .stringType("key1")
        .closeObject();
```

this creates a matching rule -

**"$.attributes.key1": {**

but i want it to handle any number of key value pair and also key can be any string

something like - **"$.attributes.*": {**

If above scenario is not supported, is there way I can check if object is not null and has some value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see `eachKeyLike`: https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer/#matching-any-key-in-a-map

This ignores the name of the key, but specifies the type of value it should have.

Comment: Thanks for Answer Mathew. But my scenario is bit different and eachKeyLike is not helpful.
eachkeyLike accepts any key, but key should be mapped to a map that has key value pairs. When i use eachkeyLike, the pact generated has empty body.

My Json request is like this -"attributes" is fixed, but key1 and key2 can be anythin
{"attributes":
{
"key1":"abc",
"key2":"xyz"
}
}

Comment: That's exactly what eachKeyLike is designed to solve. You say that "each key should be mapped to a map", but your example has just one map, with keys "key1", "key2" .... eachKeyLike on "attributes" would allow a map that had any keys, but you have to know the type/structure of the value. jump into slack.pact.io and chat there for more help.